# How to find number of pages scanned by the operator in sql-server query?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, sql-execution-plan

I need to find number of pages scanned by the operator in a sql-server query plan.
I used

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

This returned number of logical, physical, read-ahead pages scanned per table,
but I need for every operator.

Moreover, I am unable to read the IO messages using JDBC  driver programs, and
I have more than 100 queries to be executed and to record number of pages read by each operator.

Is there any method to at least get number of pages per table, that can be accessed by JDBC driver programs

OR

Is there any flag kind of thing to be set to get the number of pages scanned in the XML PLAN Itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the IO messages, informational and warning messages generated during query execution can be retrieved in JDBC with `getWarnings`. Below is a prepared statement example.

```
try (
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://yourserver:1433;databaseName=AdventureWorks;user=youruserid;password=y0urp@ssw0rd;");
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement ("SET STATISTICS IO ON;SELECT * FROM Person.Person WHERE BusinessEntityID = ?;");
    ) {
    ps.setInt(1, 1);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

    //consume result set(s)
    do {
        if(!rs.isClosed()) {
            while(rs.next()) {}
            rs.close();
        }
    } while(ps.getMoreResults());

    //get info and warning messages (including statistic io messages)
    SQLWarning w = ps.getWarnings();
    while(w != null) {
        System.out.println(w.getMessage());
        w = w.getNextWarning();
    }

} catch (SQLException e1) {
    throw e1;
}
```

Your other questions are better answered in your [dba.stackexchange question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212101/is-there-any-way-to-find-the-number-of-pages-read-by-each-operator-in-query-plan).

Comment: The mistake I did was , trying to get the warning messages before completely iterating to the resultset. I think that was the mistake I did